# Pixel 3 not detected by VSCode Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug my flutter application on a Pixel 3 connected via USB. I've used a nexus already so i'm just trying a newer Google phone. I have the developer mode on and my surface pro recognizes it but VSCode says no device. Ive gotten this to work with older android phones so i'm not sure what else needs to be set up for it to work.

I've run `flutter doctor` and it says **No devices available**.

Comment: Did you try `flutter devices` in console? what was the output?

Comment: C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge>flutter devices
No devices detected.

Run 'flutter emulators' to list and start any available device emulators.

Or, if you expected your device to be detected, please run "flutter doctor" to diagnose potential issues, or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/ for troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have the developer mode on and my surface pro recognizes it but VSCode says no device.

If you are connecting a new device, it is possible that adb is not authorized on device.
It is possible that you dismissed/missed the dialog for USB debugging authorization where it shows RSA Key.
Go to the **Developer options** on the phone and click "**Revoke USB debugging authorization**", then connect your phone again and the dialog should appear:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is flutter plugin could not detect android sdk 
try and run this command :

```
flutter config --android-sdk [android-sdk-path]
```

Answer (score 0):

My Pixel 3A has a USB "C" connector type. After I had removed and reinserted the cable about 100 times with no joy, I flipped the connector over, and magically the "RSA key" dialog appeared.

I may just have a wonky cable...